# How to apply if the extension is scss

Tags: html, css, sass

If the extension is scss, it will not be imported. (I don't use frameworks like vue js, angular js.)

Here is what my directory looks like:

src

ㅡindex.html

ㅡa.css

ㅡb.scss

**case 1 (.css)**

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="a.css" />
</head>
```

=> In case 1, the style is applied.

**case 2 (.scss)**

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="b.scss" />
</head>
```

=> In case 2, the style is not  applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't import a CSS preprocessor like that! In this case you'll need to compile the Sass file into a normal .css file, which can be done pretty easily by installing Sass on the command line, and then running one simple command to compile the `.scss` file!

See here: https://sass-lang.com/install

You can download Sass from Github here: https://github.com/sass/dart-sass/releases/tag/1.23.7. Just download the right file, unzip it and add the resulting folder to your path!

You can also install Sass with NPM via the command line, if you don't have Node.js already you can download it from https://nodejs.org/en/. Then run `npm install -g sass` to install Sass!

Once Sass is installed, you will be able to compile `.scss` files to `.css` files, for example:

```
sass b.scss b.css
```

Running this in the directory should work!

Comment: I didn't know it was my first time using sass. Thank you for answer.

Answer (score 2):

Sass (`.scss`) is a CSS *preprocessor* and cannot be imported to an HTML document like a standard CSS file -- it needs to be *compiled* to CSS file.

This is typically done through [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/) and the `node-sass` [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/) package using the command `npm run scss`, or alternatively with Gulp scripts (which can also cover things like transpilation and minification).

Having said that, you *can* achieve compilation without NodeJS, using online tools like [Sass2CSS](https://www.sass2css.online/).

Comment: I didn't know it was my first time using sass. Thank you for answer.